# "The file phpC128.tmp could not be saved. An unknown error has occurred. File upload error. Could not move uploaded file."

Tags: files

I have Drupal 8.4 running on Windows Server 2016, and when trying to use an upload field on a content type I get this error

> The file phpC128.tmp could not be saved. An unknown error has occurred.
> File upload error. Could not move uploaded file.

I deleted the *files* folder and the account PHP is running under, recreated it for this month as expected, but this still errors out. I see the file in c:\windows\temp, but it doesn't make it to my site folder. The account has full control to the *files* and *2018-06* folders.

In IIS, the AppPool is running under *ApplicationPoolIdentity* as well.

Comment: That error usually suggests the server can't write to the target folder - to debug, add a tiny standalone vanilla PHP file to the project which writes a file to the public files folder. If that works fine, you know the problem is somewhere in Drupal, otherwise it's folder permissions or some other environmental factor

Comment: a basic copy into that folder works, now what?

Answer (score 0):

Moving the file path from `c:\windows\temp' to another location, and after setting the IUSR permissions on that new folder, it worked as expected!